# Getting Py4JJavaError Pyspark error on using rdd

Tags: pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I am getting the below error:

```
py4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling z:org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRDD.collectAndServe.
```

on this line:

```
result = df.select('student_age').rdd.flatMap(lambda x: x).collect()
```

'student_age' is a column name. It was running fine until last week but now this error.

Does anyone have any insights on that?

Comment: Could you share more about the error log and your code?

Comment: Is this the full stack trace? Also, "running fine until last week" -- have you updated anything recently like java version? Also, where are you running this?

Comment: no nothing has changed

Comment: all logs:
https://ctxt.io/2/AADge2-UFg

Comment: @Slickmind could you show your code of `data_percentage` and `count_percentage` function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using collect is dangerous for this very reason, It's prone to Out Of Memory  errors.  I suggest removing it.  You also do not need to use a rdd for this you can do this with a data frame:

```
result = df.select(explode(df['student_age'])) #returns a dataFrame
#write code to use a data frame instead of any array.
```

If nothing else changed, likely the data did, and finally outgrew the size in memory.

It's also possible that you have new 'bad' data that is throwing an error.

Either way you could likely prove this by find this(OOM) or prove the data is bad by printing it.

```
def f(row):
    print(row.student_age)

result.foreach(f) # used for simple stuff that doesn't require heavy initialization.
```

IF that works you may want to break your code down to use foreachPartition.  This will let you do math on each value in the memory of each executor.  The only trick is that within `fun` below as you are executing this code on the executor you cannot reference anything that uses sparkContext. (Python code only instead of Pyspark).

```
def f(rows):
    #intialize a database connection here
    for row in rows:
        print(row.student_age) # do stuff with student_age
    #close database connection here

result.foreachPartition(f) # used for things that need heavy initialization
```

[Spark foreachPartition vs foreach | what to use?](https://sparkbyexamples.com/spark/spark-foreachpartition-vs-foreach-explained/#:%7E:text=In%20Spark%20foreachPartition()%20is,RDD%2FDataFrame%2FDataset%20partition.)

Comment: Thanks Matt!
Let me try it!

Answer (score 0):

This issue is solved, here is the answer:

```
result = [i[0] for i in df.select('student_age').toLocalIterator()]
```

Comment: This may work for your use case as it does decrease memory pressure using an iterator instead of a collect().  You are not doing pyspark at this point you are doing python coding.  That is to say, principally, you are using a `small` data approach instead of using `big` data approach.   I'd encourage you to think bigger and use dataFrames over using python arrays.  It will scale better.

Comment: I am getting this error:
********
    File "C:\Users\Jarvis\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\pyspark\sql\column.py", line 470, in __iter__
    raise TypeError("Column is not iterable")
*********************
result = df.select(explode(df['student_age']))
unique_result = list(set([j for i in result for j in xs]))

Comment: You are still using Python instead of pyspark. To make the Colum unique just call `distinct()` on it. You might benefit from more studying of pyspark.  Clearly you know Python.